# Broadcast or peer discovery with PeerJS

Tags: javascript, p2p, webrtc, peerjs

I am evaluating `PeerJS` in order to implement a simple two-player online game. It seems that once I transfer the `id` of one player’s connection to the other, they can open a channel via PeerJS and are good to go.

But if two players want to play that do not know each other, what is the most elegant way to make a match there? Is there a way to ask the PeerJS broker for a list of all connected clients, possibly with some metadata (such as „status:wants-to-play”) attached? Or is ther ea way to broadcast to all clients?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Using [PeerServer](https://github.com/peers/peerjs-server) you can grab two events, `connection` and `disconnect`. Using this you can create a internal list, which you can then have your application grab from.

Partial example:

```
var PeerServer = require('peer').PeerServer;
var server = new PeerServer({port: 9000, path: '/myapp'});
var connected = [];
server.on('connection', function (id) {
  var idx = connected.indexOf(id); // only add id if it's not in the list yet
  if (idx === -1) {connected.push(id);}
});
server.on('disconnect', function (id) {
  var idx = connected.indexOf(id); // only attempt to remove id if it's in the list
  if (idx !== -1) {connected.splice(idx, 1);}
});
someexpressapp.get('/connected-people', function (req, res) {
  return res.json(connected);
});
```

Then, in your clientside code you can AJAX `/connected-people` and use that list.

For metadata you could expand on the code above to add a user status and a way of updating that status.

Hope this helps!

**EDIT** At the time of writing the event was named `connect`. It is now named `connection`.

(Also I'm now going to play with PeerJS for like six hours. I hope you realize what you've done.)

Comment: @ZekeSonxx `Object.keys( server._clients.peerjs );` the same array

Comment: You can also pass the option `allow_discovery: true` when creating the peer server. Then just use the method `peer.listAllPeers` in the browser. I think this is not documented on the peerjs website.

Comment: I edited in `indexOf` checks, because network events are unreliable so it could be we miss one or two. With the added checks the event listeners become [idempotent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Idempotence).

Comment: There is more info on peer.listAllPeers() here: https://github.com/peers/peerjs/issues/173

The method uses a callback:

```peer.listAllPeers((allPeers)=> {
  console.log(allPeers)
})```

Comment: I think listAllPeers works the purpose, but how do discover the peers who join later this call? can this peer server also push messages to the client?

Answer (score 3):

Just in case, if this helps someone, if you use PeerJS in conjunction with express server, this would look the following way:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var server = require('http').createServer(app);
var ExpressPeerServer = require('peer').ExpressPeerServer;
var expressPeerServer = ExpressPeerServer(server, {});
app.use('/peerjs', expressPeerServer);
expressPeerServer.on('connection', function (id) {
  // the rest is the same as accepted answer
});
```